# Why this JS code writting to a hole file so slow on Windows and how to improve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

```js
var
fs = require('fs'),
target = 'test',
size = 2 * 1024 ** 3,
content = Buffer.from('TEST'),

fd = fs.openSync(target,'w');

console.time('Truncate')
fs.ftruncateSync(fd,size)
console.timeEnd('Truncate')
fs.closeSync(fd)

console.log(fs.statSync(target).size)
fd = fs.openSync(target,'r+')

console.time('Write to 1GB position')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,size / 2)
console.timeEnd('Write to 1GB position')

console.time('Write to 0.5GB position')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,size / 4)
console.timeEnd('Write to 0.5GB position')

console.time('Write to 2GB position')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,size - 100)
console.timeEnd('Write to 2GB position')

console.time('Write to 1GB position again')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,100 + size / 2)
console.timeEnd('Write to 1GB position again')

console.time('Write to 2GB position again')
fs.writeSync(fd,content,0,content.length,size - content.length)
console.timeEnd('Write to 2GB position again')

fs.closeSync(fd)
```

Output from a x86_64 Windows 10

```
Truncate: 4.559ms
2147483648
Write to 1GB position: 5195.480ms
Write to 0.5GB position: 0.096ms
Write to 2GB position: 6506.196ms
Write to 1GB position again: 0.032ms
Write to 2GB position again: 0.023ms
```

And on Ubuntu 16.04 in a virtual machine running on the Windows above

```
Truncate: 0.380ms
2147483648
Write to 1GB position: 0.311ms
Write to 0.5GB position: 0.021ms
Write to 2GB position: 0.330ms
Write to 1GB position again: 0.010ms
Write to 2GB position again: 0.011ms
```

Both using the latest node executable

The results are the same even if I remove the `truncate` part, which is what I thought the cause of slow

Please help me improve it
Thanks

Comment: This should be on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: @kemicofa Oops, should i then close this and ask on CodeReview?

Comment: No, just ask the same question on Code Review.